# Configure DynamoDB stream trigger with insert only

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I currently have an AWS DynamoDB stream triggers a Lambda function.

The Lambda function is triggered by both **insert** and **update** events in the DynamoDB. Is there a way to change the configuration so that the Lambda function would **only** be triggered by 'insert'?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To my knowledge this is not possible.  [AWS Lambda *polls* the stream](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) and invokes your Lambda function when it detects any type of stream record update. Your Lambda will have to ignore the records that you are not interested in. You can use the [eventName property](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dynamodbstreams/latest/APIReference/API_Record.html) of the stream record (can have values INSERT | MODIFY | REMOVE)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but using Lambda functions to ignore the records would cause an unnecessary cost of invoking the Lambda. I really feel AWS should make this configurable.

Comment: Yeah AWS, a little Customer Obsession here please?

Comment: Still this is not supported by AWS?

Answer (score 7):

You can use your lambda function to ignore rest other than insert.

```
 for record in event.get('Records'):
    if record.get('eventName') in ('INSERT'):
       """ code for execution. """

    elif record.get('eventName') == 'REMOVE':
        pass
    elif record.get('eventName') ==  'MODIFY':
        pass
```

Comment: Paying for lambda invocations that we won't use doesn't seem like good architecture

Comment: There's no such eventName as DELETE, or at least not anymore. Replace with **REMOVE** instead.

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer was accurate this is now supported by [Lambda Event Filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html#filtering-syntax) leveraging event source mappings.

```bash
aws lambda create-event-source-mapping \
    --function-name my-function \
    --event-source-arn arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:123456789012:my-queue \
    --filter-criteria "{\"Filters\": [{\"Pattern\": \"{ \"a\" : [ 1, 2 ]}\"}]}"
```

Furthermore, you can include this in your Cloud formation or CDK workflow. See the accepted answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70363945/filter-criteria-in-lambda-function) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In general, not only for nodejs but all types, this is supported for **non global** tables. Good collection of filter snippets can found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html).

You basically apply filtering on Lambda service side before function gets triggered.

PS, Also great [article](https://dev.to/aws-builders/new-dynamodb-streams-filtering-in-serverless-framework-3lc5) explaining how it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream filters now and filter for those event types that you need only:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.Tutorial2.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34446906)