# Filter Criteria in Lambda Function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I want to enable DynamoDB streams on my lambda using AWS CDK which I am able to do but I also want to enable the [filter criteria](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/aws-lambda-event-filtering-amazon-sqs-dynamodb-kinesis-sources/) on lambda

But I am getting this error:

> Invalid filter pattern definition. (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException

This is the event I am getting from DynamoDB streams:

```json
{
    "input": {
        "Records": [
            {
                "eventID": "e92e0072a661a06df0e62e411f",
                "eventName": "INSERT",
                "eventVersion": "1.1",
                "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb",
                "awsRegion": "<region>",
                "dynamodb": {
                    "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1639500357,
                    "Keys": {
                        "service": {
                            "S": "service"
                        },
                        "key": {
                            "S": "key"
                        }
                    },
                    "NewImage": {
                        "service": {
                            "S": "service"
                        },
                        "channel": {
                            "S": "email"
                        },
                        "key": {
                            "S": "key"
                        }
                    },
                    "SequenceNumber": "711500000000015864417",
                    "SizeBytes": 168,
                    "StreamViewType": "NEW_IMAGE"
                },
                "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:dynamodb:<region>:<account>:table/table-name/stream/2021-12-14T13:00:29.888"
            }
        ]
    },
    "env": {
        "lambdaContext": {
            "callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop": true,
            "functionVersion": "$LATEST",
            "functionName": "functionName",
            "memoryLimitInMB": "128",
            "logGroupName": "/aws/lambda/functionName",
            "logStreamName": "2021/12/14/[$LATEST]028531c7b489b8ec69bace700acc0",
            "invokedFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<account>:function:functionName",
            "awsRequestId": "c72e80252-4722-b9f0-a03b7f8b820e"
        },
        "region": "<region-name>"
    }
}
```

The event source mapping code is:

```js
const mapping = new lambda.CfnEventSourceMapping(this, 'event', {
  functionName: "functionName,
  batchSize: 1,
  bisectBatchOnFunctionError: true,
  startingPosition: lambda.StartingPosition.TRIM_HORIZON,
  eventSourceArn: <stream-arn>,
  filterCriteria: filter,
});
```

I want to get the eventName to be `INSERT` and the channel to be email here. What should be the value of the filter criteria? Its not working for me

Comment: And how is `filter` defined?

Comment: examples how filters are define can be checked here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html#filtering-syntax

Comment: I'm talking about the variable `filter`. Share the code where you define it.

Comment: I am using this 
const filter ={
 "Filters": [{
  "Pattern": "{ \"eventName\": [ \"INSERT\" ] }"
 }]
}
and it is not working , Also I want to get channel = email from the dynamodb

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### <Edit> CDK filter helpers added in v2.42.0

The original workaround is no longer necessary. The CDK now has event-source [filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.FilterCriteria.html) for Lambda, Kinesis and SQS. Pass the filter to the L2 `EventSourceMapping` construct:

```js
const source: EventSourceMapping = new lambda.EventSourceMapping(this, "EventSourceMapping",{
    target: func,
    eventSourceArn: table.tableStreamArn,
    startingPosition: lambda.StartingPosition.TRIM_HORIZON,
    filters: [
      lambda.FilterCriteria.filter({
        eventName: lambda.FilterRule.isEqual("INSERT"),
        dynamodb: {  NewImage: { channel: { S: lambda.FilterRule.isEqual("email") } },},
      }),
    ],
  }
);
```

#### </Edit>

---

Here's the DynamoDB streams filter `Pattern` syntax for new records with a `channel` of `email`:

```js
`{ \"eventName\": [\"INSERT\"], \"dynamodb\": { \"NewImage\": {\"channel\": { \"S\" : [\"email\"]}} } }`
```

In other words, the `Pattern` is a stringified JSON [filter rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html#filtering-syntax) with escaped quotes.  The pattern is applied against each stream record.

Here is the full CDK syntax.  The code starts with the usual L2 `EventSourceMapping`. It then uses [escape hatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html) syntax to set `FilterCriteria` on the [underlying L1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html#cfn_layer_cfn) `CfnEventSourceMapping`:

```js
// start with the L2 type - Note: the OP code starts with a L1 `CfnEventSourceMapping`
const source: EventSourceMapping = new lambda.EventSourceMapping(this, 'EventSourceMapping', {
  target: func,
  eventSourceArn: table.tableStreamArn,
  startingPosition: lambda.StartingPosition.TRIM_HORIZON,
});

// escape hatch - get a L1 reference
const cfnSouce = source.node.defaultChild as lambda.CfnEventSourceMapping;

cfnSouce.addPropertyOverride('FilterCriteria', {
  Filters: [
    {
      Pattern: `{ \"eventName\": [\"INSERT\"], \"dynamodb\": { \"NewImage\": {\"channel\": { \"S\" : [\"email\"]}} } }`,
    },
  ],
});
```

Comment: It is still not working initially it gave me error in cfnSource.addPropertyOverride that cannot access properties of undefined so i changed it to
cfnSource?.addPropertyOverride and it i think cfnSource is undefined that is why the resultant cloudformation prepared has no changes. Is it working for you ?? .

Comment: Yes, the answer's code deploys as expected.  Your error is probably due to mixing up [L1 (`Cfn*`) and L2 types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html#cfn_layer_cfn).   My answer starts with the L2 `source: EventSourceMapping` and gets a reference to its L1 child node `cfnSouce: CfnEventSourceMapping`. You _start with_ the L1 construct: `mapping: CfnEventSourceMapping`.  Both approaches work fine if done properly.   I edited the answer to make our different starting points clearer.

Comment: To make it dead simple: if your `mapping` is already a `CfnEventSourceMapping`, you can call
`mapping.addPropertyOverride` without the `.node.defaultChild` line.

Comment: Yes its working thanks a lot

Comment: Instead of using `addPropertyOverride()`, which takes any string and an `any` value, you should use the `filterCriteria` property. For example: `cfnSourceMapping.filterCriteria = <FilterCriteriaProperty>{ filters: [{ pattern: "" }] }`. This gives you the benefit of property and type checking.